# Cannot convert from Flux<Object> to Flux<BOLCompliance>

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm getting this error in the below method in line
"return Mono.justOrEmpty(routeLink.getComplianceIds())"

```
   private Flux<BOLCompliance> getComplienceRouteLink(BOLRouteLink routeLink, BillOfLadingResponse bol) {
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(routeLink.getComplianceIds())
            .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable)
            .flatMap(id -> complianceCaller.getComplianceById(id))
            .map(compliance -> createComplianceResponse(compliance, bol));
    }
```

routeLink.getComplianceIds() returns a List of type String,
createComplianceResponse returns a Mono of type BOLCompliance and complianceCaller.getComplianceById(id)) returns a Mono of type Compliance

```
public Mono<Compliance> getComplianceById(String complianceID);
private Mono<BOLCompliance> createComplianceResponse(Compliance compliance, BillOfLadingResponse bol);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your

```
.map(compliance -> createComplianceResponse(compliance, bol));
```

Should be

```
.flatMap(compliance -> createComplianceResponse(compliance, bol));
```

As your return type is `Mono<BOLCompliance>` for `createComplianceResponse`, and you want the `BOLCompliance` to go further down the stream, not the `Mono` objects. In your example the resulting Flux is `Flux<Mono<BOLCompliance>>`.